# Apache tomcat error-http status 404

Tags: tomcat8

//code for my application:-
when i run my application and open the logout or profile page i.e. i click on logout or profile links then the error 404 resource not found occurs     //index.html

```
 <h1>Welcome to login pannel</h1>
    <a href="login.html">Login</a>
    <a href="logoutservlet">Logout</a>
    <a href="profileservlet">Profile</a>
```

//link.html

```
<a href="login.html">Login</a> |  
<a href="LogoutServlet">Logout</a> |  
<a href="ProfileServlet">Profile</a>
```

//login.html

```
<form action="loginservlet" method="post">
Name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="pass"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form>
```

//loginservlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
/* Servlet implementation class loginservlet
 */
@WebServlet("/loginservlet")
public class loginservlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
        req.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(req, res);
        String name=req.getParameter("name");
        String pass=req.getParameter("pass");
           if(pass.equals("1234")){  
                out.print("You are successfully logged in!");  
                out.print("<br>Welcome, "+name);  

                Cookie ck=new Cookie("name",name);  
                res.addCookie(ck);  
            }else{  
                out.print("sorry, username or password error!");  
                req.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(req, res);  
            }  

            out.close();  
    }

}
```

//profileservlet.java//

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class profileservlet
 */
@WebServlet("/profileservlet")
public class profileservlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public profileservlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          res.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();  

            req.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(req, res);  

            Cookie ck[]=req.getCookies();  
            if(ck!=null){  
             String name=ck[0].getValue();  
            if(!name.equals("")||name!=null){  
                out.print("<b>Welcome to Profile</b>");  
                out.print("<br>Welcome, "+name);  
            }  
            }else{  
                out.print("Please login first");  
                req.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(req, res);  
            }  
            out.close(); 
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

}
```

//logoutservlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class logoutservlet
 */
@WebServlet("/logoutservlet")
public class logoutservlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        res.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();  


        req.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(req, res);  

        Cookie ck=new Cookie("name","");  
        ck.setMaxAge(0);  
        res.addCookie(ck);  

        out.print("you are successfully logged out!"); 
        //res.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(req.getContextPath());
    }

}
```

//web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>log_in_out</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Show us your project structure

Comment: i have tried editing web.xml. no effect.

Comment: index.html-->takes username and pass-->if correct request dispatched to loginservlet.java-->then you can visit profile by clicking on profile link or logout by clicking on logout link

Comment: error occurs when i click on logout link or profile